# What does NOM stand for in a datasheet and what does it mean?

Tags: datasheet, terminology

The question is in reference to: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls00.pdf

Comment: More definitions here: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nom%20nom%20nom

Answer (score 13, accepted):

NOM = Nominal, that's the value you normally can expect, and what the device is designed to.

Note that nominal values are often not the best to calculate with. If you want to go worst case you'll have to calculate with Minimum or Maximum, depending on the parameter and the application.

Comment: Can you imagine any calculation at all for which you would use the nominal value?

Comment: @Wouter - Me? Hardly, unless that's the only value given. Tables in datasheets may give you MIN, NOM and MAX, graphs are often only NOM. But I sometimes have a hard time to convince others. Interns often do it. Bad Habit™.

Comment: OK, we agree. ABSOLUTE MAXIMA and NOMINAL values are almost useless.